# e.preventDefault being ignored on form submitting

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When I click any of the buttons as seen below the php page getkey.php is being opened when it shouldn't be because I'm using e.preventDefault(); and the id="getgame" is the same as in my javascript code. This is annoying me because everything besides e.preventDefault(); is functioning as intended. value="" is being passed via $_GET["appid"] and it is responding with 0 as 1.

```
<form action="getkey.php" method="get" class="getgame">
<button name="appid" type="submit" value="112">Request</button>
</form>

<form action="getkey.php" method="get" class="getgame">
<button name="appid" type="submit" value="113">Request</button>
</form>

<form action="getkey.php" method="get" class="getgame">
<button name="appid" type="submit" value="114">Request</button>
</form>

 <script>
 $(function(){
$('form.getgame').on('submit', function(e){    
         // prevent native form submission here
    e.preventDefault();

    // now do whatever you want here
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // <-- get method of form
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // <-- get action of form
        data: $(this).serialize(), // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#result').html('');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);



 if(data === "0") {
 alert("foo");
  }

 if(data === "1") {
 alert("bar");
  }



             }
         });
     });     
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: If you don't want it to submit to getkey.php, why not change the type from `submit` to `button`? Also, if you have the same ID for your forms, it's going to do odd things in javascript, like ignore functions past the first form.

Comment: You are using the same id for multiple elements. This makes all further discussion moot.

Comment: After my edits If I use e.preventDefault(); then I get an alert(""); without a page change which is intended, however data === is returning NULL. If I manually visit getkey.php?appid=114 for example it will echo '0' or '1'. Something else must be wrong with the javascript or html.

Comment: put `echo 1; exit();` at the very start of your PHP script to see if that changes anything. Just to exclude a problem in your PHP file.

Comment: It echoes 1. For some reason javascript isnt passing the variable via GET.

Comment: *It echoes one:* you mean in Javascript on the submit click? If so, I think it is time you include your PHP code in this question.

Comment: Yes. If it's my php code then why can I manually visit the url and it will var_dump the correct appid      ie: getkey.php?appid=114    outputs 114

Comment: True, could you log the value of `$(this).serialize()` just before calling `$.ajax()` to make sure it is `appid=114`

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry my javascript skills are nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you cannot use same id for more than one element.

change your all form's `id` attributes as `class`, like this

`<form action="getkey.php" method="get" class="getgame">`

and then in your JS, use `return false;` instead of `e.preventDefault()`

like this

```
$('form.getgame').on('submit', function(e){    
     //your ajax stuffs here
     return false;
});
```

Note : 
jQuery `serialize()` doesn't include `button` or `input[type=submit]` so you will have to add it manually

So your JS would looks like

```
$(function(){
    $('form.getgame').on('submit', function(e){        
        // now do whatever you want here
        var appid = $(this).find("button[type=submit]").attr("value");
       $.ajax({
           type: $(this).attr('method'), // <-- get method of form
           url: $(this).attr('action'), // <-- get action of form
           data: { "appid" : appid }, // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
           beforeSend: function(){
               $('#result').html('');
           },
           success: function(data){
               $('#result').html(data);
               if(data === "0") {
                   alert("foo");
               }
               if(data === "1") {
                   alert("bar");
               }
            }
        });    
       // prevent native form submission here
       return false;       
    });     
});
```

Comment: Alright if I use return false and I click the button nothing happens. If I use e.preventDefault(); then I get an alert(""); without a page change which is intended, however data === is returning NULL. If I manually visit getkey.php?appid=114 for example it will echo '0' or '1'. Something else must be wrong with the javascript or html.

Comment: at the end of your `getkey.php` ( after the `echo` statement ) have you put the `exit();` statement .?

Comment: You can also inspect your Ajax request by using your browser's Dev Console ( use the Network Tab )

in your FF or Chrome press `Ctrl + Shift + i` you will get the Dev Console

Comment: Yes I use die(); javascript is not passing the appid value="" to $GET['appid];